# How to install Toad for MySQL in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, toad

I need step by step guidance, for **how to install Toad for MySQL in Ubuntu 12.04** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`toad` not available for Ubuntu.

But you can try with [Tora](http://torasql.com/).

You can install Tora from `Ubuntu software center`.

Or

install from command line using `sudo apt-get install tora`

Comment: ok may i know what's the difference between Toad and Tora, and steps to install Tora

Comment: install Tora from `ubunut software center`

Comment: Is it requires WINE Installed, before installing it or not?

Comment: No. `sudo apt-get install tora`. Run this command from terminal